# Endline character problem in reading files

Tags: c++, import, buffer, iostream

I have a function that reads the file to the buffer `std::vector<char>` and then through variadic templates parses row by row to containers.

I found a problem with the buffer with `\n` character.

This is an input file (UTF-8):
H,1,
H,2,

This is in hex:
48 2C 31 2C 0D 0A 48 2C 32 2C 0D 0A

H  ,  1  ,  .  .  H  ,  2  ,  .  .

Now I have code that imports that to the buffer (different checks are purposely omitted):

```
std::ifstream in ("file.txt");
in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
std::streampos fileLength = in.tellg();
in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
std::vector<char> buf (fileLength);
in.read(&buf[0], fileLength);
in.close ();
```

However if I print the buffer this way (using same principle to import into containers):

```
void printHex (std::vector<char>& buffer)
{
    std::size_t noOfChar {buffer.size()};
    std::cout << "Number of chars: " << noOfChar << "\n";
    for (std::size_t i {0}; i < noOfChar; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << buffer[i];
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (std::size_t i {0}; i < noOfChar; ++i)
    {
        sum += (buffer[i]);
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') 
                  << static_cast<int>(buffer[i]) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I get this:

*Number of chars: 12
H,1,
H,2,
48 2c 31 2c 0a 48 2c 32 2c 0a 00 00*

I have tried different input with more data and clearly, hex **0D 0A** are read into buffer as only **0A**.
The solution could be relatively easy, trim all excess **00** at the end of the buffer so that they are not taken later by function parsing rows.

But my questions are:

1. Why this is doing that '\n' character is saved into file as **0D 0A** and imported back as '\n' character
2. Is there better way how to handle '\n' through import into streamstring buffer?

Comment: When reading streams open in text-mode, reading from the stream might include newline transformations. Most notably the Windows newline sequence `\r\n` is translated to a single `\n`. The opposite translation is done when writing. Seeking a file does not do this translation, it's done byte-wise.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How can I do it? [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open) shows only binary mode.

Comment: The default mode when opening a file, if `ios::binary` is not mentioned, is to open in text mode. Do you need the *full* raw binary content of the file? Then open in binary mode. Otherwise you could use `std::istream_iterator` to read the file into the vector (without setting its size) in one go, but note that it will use the normal stream extraction operator `>>` so will skip space by default (can be changed). What are you really doing? Are you trying to read a CSV (or similarly) formatted file?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, ios::binary works. Yes, its csv or any other type with specified delimiter. Firstly, I have tried reading file line by line using std::getline but after that I decided to use firstly buffering the file and stream operators and I will compare both methods. It seems me that using operators << >> is better than having std::string for non numerical values as it could be easily used for parsing class as there will be needed only overloading << >> operators instead constructor from std::string which could be potentially dangerous.

Comment: To be honest, CSV and similar formats tend to have way too many corner-cases where parsing them becomes very hard. Unless it's for a school assignment or similar, I recommend you find a library to handle the file reading and parsing for you. Will make your life much simpler in the long run.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, it is for hobby programming where the program use reading and writing for various reasons, saving or debugging states, data etc. This is the reason I do not want use some larger library but still have relatively abstract way to store data, classes etc. And as just hobby programmer it is for me way to learn things.

Comment: Noted, and a good reason. :-) But still, once you've learned please still use libraries for future projects. Even if it's your own time, it still is worth something more than fixing obscure bugs or corner cases. Better spend the time on your core problem or logic. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first, question, this goes into the history of ASCII line feed character. On linux, newline is typically signified by `'\x0a'` character (`\n`). On windows newline is signified by `\x0d` (`\r`) character (which returns the cursor to the beginning of the line, followed by `\x0a` (`\n`) character (which puts the cursor on line below, same column.

In C++ in order to provide an abstraction, for *text streams* they do an implicit conversion. When you type `\n` it converts it either to `\n` or `\r\n` on different platforms. This could lead to problems if you were trying to read a binary file. Which is why input streams take a second flag for the kind of stream you want to open -- text or binary.

In order to answer the second question, just slap `std::ios::binary` as the second parameter, this would open stream as binary and should avoid implicit line ending conversions.

```
std::ifstream in("file.txt", std::ios::binary);
```

I would recommend opening all files in binary mode if you're trying to read the whole file into the buffer and get it's length by seeking: getting the length of text file that way is dangerous and can lead to bugs related to reading of uninitialized memory (you're reading less characters into the buffer than there actually are).

This also means you have to handle `\r` manually.